# WPF Validation with ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, validation, binding, idataerrorinfo, caliburn

I have a WPF user control which needs to validate some fields.  It is bound to a class implementing IDataErrorInfo.

When I set the user control as the content of my ContentPresenter in another, already open, window, I can see validation occurring, and error messages being returned, however, I don't get any validation adorner - e.g. the default red outline.

If I enter the field and leave it (triggering re-validation) the validation adorner appears.

Also, if I show the user control in it's own window it shows the validation adorner immediately.

(I'm using Caliburn IResults to do this underneath, e.g. `Show.Dialog<VM>();` but I suspect this isn't related)

Can anyone offer any suggestion why the validation adorners aren't appearing immediately.  (I had guessed animation on my ContentPresenter ContentChanged, however, I have removed this and still experience the problem.

thanks, 
Chris

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5, or 4?  I want to say that this "bug" is fixed in WPF 4, but I can't say for sure.  Can you provide some source code and I'll try it in .NET 4?

Comment: Brent - you are correct - I tried myself with 4 and it was fine, while 3.5 didn't work.

Have you any suggestions for a workaround with 3.5, or should I upgrade.

Thanks so much - have spent too long trying to solve this.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/120257/ValidationSample.zip

Comment: I don't know of a workaround other than checking out this post...
http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/8573/40940.aspx
I looked at your source code and saw the same issue you were having.  Personally, I would upgrade to .NET 4 rather than implementing a workaround, but that's just me.  Good luck!

Comment: upgrade complete - thanks for the help - if you want to add an answer, i'll mark it as then answered one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that exists in .NET 3.5.  You may be able to implement a [workaround](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/8573/40940.aspx), however if it is feasible, I would recommend upgrading to .NET 4 as this will take care of your issue with validation.